# Can't setup the main class in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Button is not active (see the screenshot). Main method exsits. Classname and Filename is ok. But when i choose Main Class - it don't accept my class. How can i fix it?

Source folder setup is ok.
JDK setup is ok.
And i think i have no code errors.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ojNC.png)

Comment: The IDE proposes you to choose the main method in the class from your preview. Cannot you select it ?

Comment: davidxxx, yes, when i select method - button is not active. I can't select it.

Comment: I think that you should update the image with which one : the cursor on the method, not on the class.

Comment: Ok. https://pasteboard.co/HYpZvVG.png

Comment: Check if there are any errors in [log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085). Try disabling 3rd plugins if you use any. Try creating new project - does it help?

Comment: Andrey, after some time if just fixed. Class found. IDK what help me. Maybe - just application restart.
About log - there is too much errors with "This feature requires ASM7" at ending.
But now all works, i think it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE has no JRE configured. When I take a look at your screenshot I see `JRE: Deafault <no JRE> ...`

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/HYpZvVG.png
It was just not selected. I install JDK, it includes JRE. Of cource i setup it in IDEA properties.

Comment: Is the button "ok" enabled if you select the class instead of the method?

Comment: Thank you for reply, Thomas Bosch. 
No, it disabled like in a first screenshot.

Comment: While this may be right, it does not solve the problem. Please provide resources how to add a JDK or explain it yourself in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do all the tings, posted before. 
Do "/src/main/java" like it Bor Laze said, mark "src" folder as source (only it).
And **restart application**. Now all is work. Idk what's happiend, maybe it was just a bug.

Problem fixed, question closed.

Answer (score -1):

File should be in src/main/java folder

Comment: Check your project properties too: File -> Project structure -> Module. Folder with class should be green (marked as 'Sources')

Comment: src/main/java, not src/main.java

Comment: Same problem. "Java" now is marked as Sources (blue folder, not green). 
And now it looks like src/main/java. I think there is another problem.
https://pasteboard.co/HYpYuYw.png